# How do I prevent my viewfinder diopter from getting miscalibrated?

Tags: nikon, diopter, nikon-df

I've had this issue with other cameras but seems especially bad with my Nikon Df. I keep the camera upside down at my side on a shoulder strap that screws to the bottom, so I think hitting against my body is what possibly makes the diopter move. It's weird because every other dial has a locking button, but the diopter is running free. This seems like a bad design since I should never have to re-adjust it unless I give my camera to someone else.

Is there a good way to solve this? or do I need to keep re-calibrating it 5x / day?

I use a [Glide One strap](http://customslr.com/collections/camera-straps/products/glide-strap); I really like this thing.. could it be damaging to the camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try gaffers tape if you never need to change the diopter. Set it and tape it down. I keep gaffers tape on the bottom of my body to protect it and usually a small piece on my lenses to tape the focus down for night photography and time-lapse.

Comment: sweet thanks! is that same as electrical tape?

Comment: @SonicSoul No, it's its own thing. It's more like duct tape, but doesn't leave a residue. More expensive, but used for many many things in the studio.

Comment: thanks.. you said "if you don't need to change the diopter" does that mean some people change it frequently?

Comment: Most of the time I have my contact lenses in (which requires a strong "+" correction for close distances). When I'm not wearing them I need a strong "-" correction for my myopia.

Comment: I did briefly consider suggesting superglue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the bad design is hanging the camera from a part that was not designed from which to have the camera be hung.

Have you tried a strap that hooks to the parts of the camera that were actually designed for a strap? A tripod socket is generally engineered to handle compressive forces. That is, it is designed to hold things up (E.g. your camera and lens) that are sitting on top of it and pressing down. Hanging the camera upside down places tension on the socket that tests the tensile strength of every part of the assembly - from the adapter you screw into the threads of the socket, to the threads themselves, to the screws that attach the socket to the floor plate, and the floor plate to which the socket is attached. When measuring tensile strength the whole assembly is never stronger than the weakest link.

I realize all of the ads for those things have really attractive super-cool looking people walking around with "Madison Avenue" grins on their faces while they look really super-cool in their super-cool clothes and their hipster mirrorless cameras hang upside down at their sides. But take a look around at the next world class sporting event you attend. Almost of those grizzled old fat guys on the sidelines with 10-15K of gear strapped on have most of it hanging by either the strap lugs on the camera or the strap lugs on those huge lenses, and are not hanging it from the tripod socket. They've been doing it long enough to know what works and what doesn't.

Comment: haha.. appreciate the cynicism. I actually love the upside down position because it's very natural to grab it quickly as my hand is also "upside down" when at my sides.. i also love that i can slide it over to the back so my sides have clearance when walking through tight spaces. updating my question with the exact strap i use

Comment: i also find that the normal strap hoops are completely in the way of camera operation :( perhaps that's a matter of getting used to

Comment: I use a similar type dual harness, but the attachment points for the right side camera are the right lug (near the shutter button) and the *strap lug* on the bottom of the grip. That holds the camera at a 90º angle and the right grip is on top when I reach for it. The left side camera is a little less elegant - the main strap hooks to the left lug (near the mode dial) and the longer safety strap that normally isn't load bearing hooks to the *strap lug* on the bottom of the camera.

Comment: It's a matter of finding the right connectors that fit between/around your hands and the camera without getting in the way. Also finding connectors that are long enough to be out of your way by the time they hook to the wider strap that goes over your shoulder or around the neck. They're not the hippest things on the market, but I really like the Op-Tec system of connectors and straps/harnesses/slings. There's an almost infinite number of combinations of the various pieces you can use to build your own that works for you.

Comment: interesting! can you please post some links to the ones you use / like ??

Comment: http://optechusa.com/straps.html

Comment: Canon gives a nice customized strap to gold and platinum members of *CPS*. It seems to be an Op-Tech Utility series main strap with the loop connectors like those found on the Pro Loop Strap. With your Df, though, the lugs are different and I would get something with the Swivel Hook connectors. If you don't like the hooks that close in, you can put some utility loops on the lugs and then hook the swivels to those. Just the old standard 3/8" webbing might also work for you.   http://optechusa.com/system-connectors.html

Comment: "A tripod socket is generally engineered to handle compressive forces" – that seems wrong. Any bolt + threaded-hole combination relies on *tension* to work. The tensile forces of the bolt provides compressive forces against the camera body when it is on a tripod, but the 1/4–20 thread itself is completely and always in tension when a tightened bolt is in it.

Comment: It still doesn't require as much tensile strength to hold a bolt in the threads as it does to hold the bolt in the threads *and* support the *additional* stress from the weight of the camera and lens. I've seen more than one camera go face down onto the pavement when the bolt snapped off flush with the socket. I've also seen a few where the entire floor plate ripped out. The bolt/socket held fine, but the floor plate didn't stay connected to the rest of the camera. Those screws are usually a lot smaller than the 1/4-20 stud in the tripod socket, even when all four are added together.

Comment: I've even seen instances where the swivels attached to the adapter stud broke, or the "wings" on the edge of the adapter stud shear off. Tensile stress always finds the weakest point in the system. Always.

Comment: And don't even think about using a swivel hook to hold onto the little D-ring on the bottom of a manfrotto 200PL-14 RC2/Q2 connector that is designed only to hand tighten the screw, not to hold anything at all. Those things only need about 4-5lbs of force to pull apart and come out of the QC plate.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/blovis/6553913433

Comment: Those in the know that do use the BR system almost always have a safety  of some kind added to catch the camera if the primary connectors fail. http://www.martinbaileyphotography.com/2011/05/29/podcast-288-camera-straps-and-safety-measures/

Comment: Aside: 100% agreed on backup for BR-type systems. Also, I would *never* use the type of screw hanger Martin Bailey was using in that photo (1/4-20 screw with a bent-wire style loop. I would much prefer a machined hole-through-head 1/4-bolt.

Comment: However, with regards to bolt shear for system mounted on tripod vs hung, there is very little difference. For a camera mounted on a tripod, the torque provided by the camera+lens provides a higher strain moment on the back side of the screw (side towards the viewfinder). For the same camera+lens hung on a sling, the net strain across the bolt's shank is actually somewhat less (due to the bolt head itself rotating with camera to hang directly above the combined center of mass). **Granted**, the shear force is higher from hanging, as well as the total tension on the bolt (i.e., the system mass)

Comment: Finally, minor nitpicking (your point is still well noted and valid), but cases of fasteners snapping off, swivels breaking, etc., are specific fastener problems, nothing to do with the camera body's ability to be supported hanging by 1/4-20 hole. However, cases where the *bottom of the camera coming off* certainly support your assertion.

Comment: Most cameras have at least two lugs, some have three. Most cameras only have a single tripod thread. All else being equal, that can be leveraged to prevent a rare failure of a redundant connector from becoming a rare catastrophe caused by the failure of the only connector. And the diopter adjust wheel is probably angled away from the body enough to not get unintentionally moved near as frequently. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The dial doesn't lock on either of my Canons but it's not easy to knock. It's also quite easy to see the position so maybe you need to mark yours with a spot of paint. That will tell you if it's off and allow you to set it back to where it should be.

Comment: hmm it's so tiny, not sure but i'll give it a shot thanks!

Comment: If it's tiny, you could apply some paint with a toothpick. If you want something less permanent, correction fluid (tippex,  white out) can often be removed with a fingernail.